# Can't Auto-Update, but permissions are good?

Tags: customization, automatic-updates

Normally wordpress will auto-update fine without a fuss, but now throws the old ftp credentials form up in my grill.

I haven't changed any permissions in between updates, even running `chmod` and `chown` recursively to be sure, but still wordpress wants the ftp.

Out of the few wordpress installations i run, this is the only one playing hard-to-update.

I'll resort to a manual update if i have to and hope it fixes itself, but it'd be great to know what's the beef.

Comment: it's usually about chown actually. what user and group are you using with chown? ngnix or apache? what's the user who runs nginx or apache?

Comment: default www-data for apache, both owner and group from the parent dir down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're pretty sure about that the file owner of wordpress folder is as same as that one who runs apache. (use `ps aux|grep 'httpd'` or `ps aux|grep 'apache'`)

Here is a **lousy** solution for you:

```
function force_use_direct_fs($method,$args){
         if($method != 'direct')
              $method = 'direct';
         return $method;
}

add_filter('filesystem_method','force_use_direct_fs',10,2);
```

**Why Would Wordpress Request FTP Credentials**

```
wp-admin/includes/file.php
```

In function `get_filesystem_method` Wordpress will determine the proper filesystem method by comparing the file owner of a temporary file to the user who runs the web server.

Here is the code:

```
if( getmyuid() == @fileowner($temp_file_name) )
       $method = 'direct';
```

That's why I still think the cause is the wrong file owner permission.